# SO login information lost

Tags: support, login, cookies

It looks like SO lost my login information that it usually defaults me when I open SO Page to and gives me "1st time user" banner. Since I don't remember my old login information had to create a new account with no badges and no questions asked or answered. What should I do to restore old login information?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-stack-overflow-accounts-users-anon

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember your profile page?

If not, Are you in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/filter/victor) list?

If not, do you remember some of your questions or answers? If yes, search some in stackoverflow search or
search in google with site:stackoverflow.com

Once you found it, send email to team@stackoverflow.com to get support to get your profile merge with new account.

Comment: Thnaks for reply. I have found my name in that list

Comment: Great! ...... :D

Comment: Also, I have 2 different accounts that I use on my home PC and my office laptop. Would they be able to merge those as well you think?

Comment: @Victor, Yes, I think so. If you found your profiles, you could try to request to stackoverflow team, I hope they could do a merge for you.